# R - plot netcdf4 data in lat and lon gridded space

Tags: r, plot, grid, coordinates, netcdf4

I am new to this kind of plotting and therefore please forgive my inexperience.

I would like to plot the max temperatures over Europe in a given `n` day.

Data can be accessed here http://www.ecad.eu/download/ensembles/data/Grid_0.44deg_rot/tx_0.44deg_rot_v16.0.nc.gz (258MB..sorry).

This is a netcdf file with 3 dimensions and 4 variables.

Here what I did:

```
library(ncdf4)
max_tmp_0_44_deg = "tx_0.44deg_rot_v16.0.nc"
max_tmp_0_44_deg = nc_open(max_tmp_0_44_deg)

# create variables
temp = ncvar_get(max_tmp_0_44_deg, 'tx')
lon = ncvar_get(max_tmp_0_44_deg, 'Actual_longitude')
lat = ncvar_get(max_tmp_0_44_deg, 'Actual_latitude')
time = ncvar_get(max_tmp_0_44_deg, 'time')
```

How can I plot a grid (lat and lon) of max temperatures in a given day?

```
max_day = temp[,,30]   #subset max temp on the 30th day
```

Then how can I plot `max_day`?

It should be quite straightforward but I couldn't find a solution yet.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `image` function:

```
temp_use <- temp[,,30]
temp_use <- round(temp_use)

n_colors <- length(table(temp_use))
image(temp_use,
    col = heat.colors(n_colors),
    xaxt = "n",
    yaxt = "n")
temp_max <- temp_use == max(temp_use, na.rm = T) & !is.na(temp_use)
temp_max[temp_max == F] <- NA
image(temp_max,
    add = T,
    col = "blue",
    xaxt = "n",
    yaxt = "n")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it seems however that the colour gradient is inverted, i.e. hot = yellow and red = cold. how can I re-inverted? thanks.

Comment: Use `col = rev(heat.colors(n_colors))` instead of `col = heat.colors(n_colors)`

Comment: BTW you can easily define your own color palette (e.g. from blue to grey to red) using something like `col = colorRampPalette(c("blue","grey","red"))(n_colors)`

Comment: is there any easy way I can overlap the Europe maps' contours?

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for that one

Comment: new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453516/add-european-contour-map-to-image-plot